# Determine Cause of Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: vb6

I have inherited a program written in VB 6 that is not working when the user tries to print.  I had some ocx files I needed to register (regsvr32), which I found using Process Monitor, but I can't see where this error is coming from.  Is it possible to find out what component the program was trying to create?  This program was written by someone else and I don't have access to anything but the original setup program.  Thanks.

Comment: You can try each of the "supported runtime files to distribute..." listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx in case one was left out of the setup. However, if the printing is using Crystal Reports, good luck. I could not find a version that would allow me to upgrade a VB6 program to print on Win 7 64 so still using XP for that app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not the old program, but something to do with Access.  I happened upon some articles dealing with this particular issue, but nothing worked.  I had to install Access 2013 32 bit in order to make this work.  I didn't really fix the cause of the problem, but I wanted to put this here to point any future sufferers they check Office and their program if they run into a similar issue.

HTH

Wade